# 01735. 00000 - "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am getting the following error:

> 907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

when I execute my procedure:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ALTER_TABLE_COLUMN_NOT_NULL(
    var_tabname   IN VARCHAR2,
    var_clname    IN VARCHAR2,
    var_defvalue  IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
  l_isnull VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
  SELECT isnull INTO l_isnull FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS  
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = var_tabname AND COLUMN_NAME  = var_clname;

  IF l_isnull = 'Y' THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || var_tabname   ||
             ' MODIFY COLUMN (' || var_clname  ||
             ' DEFAULT ' || var_defvalue || ' NOT NULL)';
  END IF;
END;
```

I know that  according to the error, the right parenthesis is missing. I tried many ways of rewriting it, but I can't manage to fix it.

I am executing my procedure the following way:

```
  BEGIN
     ALTER_TABLE_COLUMN_NOT_NULL('FIRSTNAME', 'PRICE', '-');
  END;
```

Comment: Do the values of `var_tabname`, `var_clname` or `var_defvalue` contain anything they shouldn't?

Comment: I editet my question, maybe I am calling the procedure in a wrong way?

Comment: Why do you show us a procedure named `ALTER_TABLE_COLUMN_NOT_NULL` when your code is trying to call procedure named `MODIFY_COLUMN_NOT_NULL`?

Comment: @Andreas 
Sry it was a typo, only in stackoverflow though, the code is still not working

Comment: So your string concatenation ends up building the statement `ALTER TABLE FIRSTNAME MODIFY COLUMN (PRICE DEFAULT - NOT NULL)`, and you wonder why it fails with `invalid ALTER TABLE option`? `DEFAULT -` is definitely wrong. --- On a side note, do you really have a table named `FIRSTNAME` with a column named `PRICE`?

Comment: No i just put some random names to avoid writing long table names, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Writing dynamic SQL is hard, because compilation errors become runtime errors.

In this case I think the problem is that `MODIFY COLUMN` is wrong syntax. It's just `MODIFY`.

You may also run into some problems with your default of `'-'`. If `price` is a number that will fail because `-` is an invalid number. If `price` is a string you'll need to escape the passed value with additional quotes.

But probably you want to make this generic, so you need to write some more sophisticated handling which tests for datatype of the target column and formats default value appropriately.

---

> "Can u give me a hint or any link how one can determine the datatype of a passed value in plsql?"

It's not the passed value which matters, it's the datatype of the modified column. You can get that from the USER_TAB_COLUMNS view which you're already querying.

Comment: Can u give me a hint or any link how one can determine the datatype of a passed value in plsql?

Answer (score 0):

Print your query to make sure it written correctly

```
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ALTER TABLE ' || var_tabname   || ' MODIFY COLUMN (' || var_clname  || ' DEFAULT ' || var_defvalue || ' NOT NULL)');
```